# using `rlang::exec` with functions that use `rlang::ensym`

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, rlang, quosure

I am trying to write a custom function which is a bit more complicated so for the sake of simplicity I have created toy examples.

Let's say I want to write a function that-

1. automatically decides the appropriate function to run: for example,
   a t-test or an anova.
2. accepts both `"quoted"` and `unquoted` arguments

So I write a function to run a t-test (works as expected):

```r
set.seed(123)
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

# t-test function
fun_t <- function(data, x, y) {
  # make sure both quoted and unquoted arguments work
  x <- rlang::ensym(x)
  y <- rlang::ensym(y)

  # t-test
  broom::tidy(stats::t.test(
    formula = rlang::new_formula({{ y }}, {{ x }}),
    data = data
  ))
}

# works fine
fun_t(mtcars, am, wt)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 10
#>   estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1.36      3.77      2.41      5.49 6.27e-6      29.2    0.853
#> # ... with 3 more variables: conf.high <dbl>, method <chr>,
#> #   alternative <chr>

fun_t(mtcars, "am", "wt")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 10
#>   estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1.36      3.77      2.41      5.49 6.27e-6      29.2    0.853
#> # ... with 3 more variables: conf.high <dbl>, method <chr>,
#> #   alternative <chr>
```

Then I write a function to run an anova (works as expected):

```r
# anova function
fun_anova <- function(data, x, y) {
  # make sure both quoted and unquoted arguments work
  x <- rlang::ensym(x)
  y <- rlang::ensym(y)

  # t-test
  broom::tidy(stats::aov(
    formula = rlang::new_formula({{ y }}, {{ x }}),
    data = data
  ))
}

# works fine
fun_anova(mtcars, cyl, wt)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   term         df sumsq meansq statistic      p.value
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 cyl           1  18.2 18.2        47.4  0.000000122
#> 2 Residuals    30  11.5  0.384      NA   NA

fun_anova(mtcars, "cyl", "wt")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   term         df sumsq meansq statistic      p.value
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 cyl           1  18.2 18.2        47.4  0.000000122
#> 2 Residuals    30  11.5  0.384      NA   NA
```

Then I write a meta-function to choose the appropriate function from above-

```r
fun_meta <- function(data, x, y) {
  # make sure both quoted and unquoted arguments work
  x <- rlang::ensym(x)
  y <- rlang::ensym(y)

  # which test to run?
  if (nlevels(data %>% dplyr::pull({{ x }})) == 2L) {
    .f <- fun_t
  } else {
    .f <- fun_anova
  }

  # executing the appropriate function
  rlang::exec(
    .fn = .f,
    data = data,
    x = x,
    y = y
  )
}

# using the meta-function
fun_meta(mtcars, am, wt)
#> Only strings can be converted to symbols

fun_meta(mtcars, "am", "wt")
#> Only strings can be converted to symbols
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here and how to get this to work?

Comment: I get the same error if I try to pass `rlang::ensym(variable)` directly into your t.test function: `fun_t(mtcars, rlang::ensym(am), wt)`.  Possibly using `rlang::ensym()` in your meta function is causing the issue?  I don't have a solution, but that might be a place to start.

Comment: I might have figured it out.  Trying using `as_string()` in your meta function to turn the arguments into strings to pass into the chosen function: `rlang::exec(.fn = .f,data = data,x = as_string(x), y = as_string(y))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the problem is stemming from passing what amounted to, e.g., `x = rlang::ensym(am)` to your individual functions via `rlang::exec()` in your meta function.

The `ensym()` function takes only strings or symbols, so doing this led to the error message.  Given this, converting your `x` and `y` arguments to strings should help.

So the meta function could be:

```
fun_meta <- function(data, x, y) {
     # make sure both quoted and unquoted arguments work
     x <- rlang::ensym(x)
     y <- rlang::ensym(y)

     # which test to run?
     if (dplyr::n_distinct(data %>% dplyr::pull({{ x }})) == 2L) {
          .f <- fun_t
     } else {
          .f <- fun_anova
     }

     # executing the appropriate function
     rlang::exec(
          .fn = .f,
          data = data,
          x = rlang::as_string(x),
          y = rlang::as_string(y)
     )
}
```

(I switched to `n_distinct()` from `nlevels` because `am` and `cyl` aren't factors and so I wasn't getting the right results to compare to your original results.)

Now using both bare symbols and strings work:

```
fun_meta(mtcars, am, wt)
    # A tibble: 1 x 10
  estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high
     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1.36      3.77      2.41      5.49 6.27e-6      29.2    0.853      1.86
# ... with 2 more variables: method <chr>, alternative <chr>
> fun_meta(mtcars, "am", "wt")

fun_meta(mtcars, "am", "wt")
# A tibble: 1 x 10
  estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high
     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1.36      3.77      2.41      5.49 6.27e-6      29.2    0.853      1.86
# ... with 2 more variables: method <chr>, alternative <chr>
```